# Deleting the container in atomic multi-threaded code

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, stdatomic

Consider the following code:

```
struct T { std::atomic<int> a = 2; };
T* t = new T();
// Thread 1
if(t->a.fetch_sub(1,std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1)
  delete t;
// Thread 2
if(t->a.fetch_sub(1,std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1)
  delete t;
```

We know exactly one of Thread 1 and Thread 2 will execute the `delete`. But are we safe? I mean suppose Thread 1 will execute the `delete`. Is it guaranteed that when Thread 1 **started** the `delete`, Thread 2 won't even read `t`?

Comment: This is not safe.

Comment: this is safe. what you do - this is by fact reference counting. if you correct manage reference - will be correct. assume you have N threads and object have N references (N == 2) in your case. every thread do so called `Release()` decrement own reference. when references reach 0 - you delete object. this is well known pattern. but need not relaxed but `memory_order_acq_rel` in general case

Comment: @super - not true. safe really. and very wide used

Comment: By "guaranteed" I mean "as far as the C++ standard is concerned (and not specific to any implementation or machine architecture)".

Comment: @Koosha - this is *guaranteed* by c++, not depend from specific to any implementation or machine architecture

Comment: I understand that this looks a lot like "reference counting". But **in this simple case**, why do I need acquire release ordering?

Comment: @Koosha - in this simple case - not need. but in general case need. if say your object containing some data fields. and you need guarantee that in destructor you view all memory modification maked by another thread. one thread say something write to object and do Release - and this will be with `memory_order_release` too. the thread which do last release - will do this and with `memory_order_acquire` - as result after this in destructor - it view all modification

Comment: @RbMm In both threads, `t` is being dereferences before the `fetch_sub`. If thread one has `delete`d `t`, and thread two does `t->` we are already in UB.

Comment: @super - no, both thread simply access `T.a` by pointer. no any UB here

Comment: @RbMm If the object pointed to by `t` is deleted, then dereferencing a pointer to it is UB.

Comment: @RbMm Please explain how `if(t->a.fetch_sub(1,std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1)` is not UB if `t` has already been deleted.

Comment: FWIW, if you use a `std::shared_ptr`, which you really should, then you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica - but this not make code incorrect and this concrete code correct. and only what we really should - deep understand waht we dooing and how it work

Comment: @super, I think what he is trying to say is that `t` will not already be deleted because `fetch_sub` returns the previous value of `a`, not the current value. Because of this, `t` won't be deleted until both threads have already read `t`.

Comment: @RbMm I'm just trying to get you out of the habit of using `new` and `delete`.  They are probably the second most common cause of bugs after off by one errors.  Smart pointers bring value semantics to dynamic allocations which makes the code much more robust and easier to maintain.  I'm not saying you shouldn't understand how it works, it just shouldn't be in production code.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I think differently, but there is no point in arguing here.

Comment: @RbMm "_both thread simply access T.a_" Forget the ptr. To even name a member of a class, the class instance must exist. That is the dtor must not have started in a diff thread. IOW the dtor start must be after the RMW decrement op.

Comment: @super I hope you are not using the std to reason about MT program. **The std does not define the behavior of an MT program.**

Comment: @curiousguy - here nothing related to MT. exist 2 `fetch_sub` calls. and `delete` called **after** both. because this and this code correct (in real life, more members will be in `T` and need `memory_order_acq_rel` in general case)

Comment: @RbMm "after" is not a well defined concept in MT code!

Comment: @curiousguy - but in case Modification order of atomic  variable we can say before and after. *All modifications to any particular atomic variable occur in a total order that is specific to this one atomic variable* - and what you say for this - https://pastebin.com/nkMptN71 ?

Comment: @curiousguy - exactly because `a.fetch_sub` is **atomic modification of same `a`** we can say about total order. about **before** and **after** - any of `a.fetch_sub` **not overlap**. and the **last** `a.fetch_sub` (which return 1) will **before** `delete`. so any `a.fetch_sub` will be **before** `delete` or in other words - `delete` will be **after** all `a.fetch_sub`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205194/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-rbmm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- let call operation `t->a.fetch_sub(1,std::memory_order_relaxed)`
  `Release`
- `Release` is atomic modification of `a`
- [*All modifications to any particular atomic variable occur in a
  total order that is specific to this one atomic variable.*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)
- so all `Release` occur in a total order
- let `Thread 1` do `Release` first and than `Thread 2` do `Release`
  after it
- so `Thread 1` view value 2 and because 2 != 1 just exit and not
  access t anymore
- `Thread 2` view value 1 and because 1 == 1 call `delete t`

note that call `delete` happens after `Release` in `Thread 2` and 
`Release` in `Thread 2` happens after `Release` in `Thread 1`

so call `delete` in `Thread 2` happens after `Release` in `Thread 1`
which not access t anymore after `Release`

but in real life (not in this concrete example) in general we need use `memory_order_acq_rel` instead `memory_order_relaxed`.

this is because the real objects usual have more data fields, not only atomic reference count.

and threads can write/modify some data in object. from another side - inside destructor we need view all modifications made by other threads.

because this every not last Release must have `memory_order_release` semantic. and last `Release` must have `memory_order_acquire` for view after this all modification . let some example

```
#include <atomic>

struct T { 
  std::atomic<int> a; 
  char* p;

  void Release() {
    if(a.fetch_sub(1,std::memory_order_acq_rel) == 1) delete this;
  }

  T()
  {
    a = 2, p = nullptr;
  }

  ~T()
  {
      if (p) delete [] p;
  }
};

// thread 1 execute
void fn_1(T* t)
{
  t->p = new char[16];
  t->Release();
}

// thread 2 execute
void fn_2(T* t)
{
  t->Release();
}
```

in destructor `~T()` we must view result of `t->p = new char[16];` even if destructor will be called in thread 2. if use `memory_order_relaxed` formal this is not guaranteed.
but with memory_order_acq_rel

thread after final `Release` , which will be executed with `memory_order_acquire` semantic too (because `memory_order_acq_rel` include it) will be view result of `t->p = new char[16];` operation because it happens before another atomic operation on the same `a` variable with `memory_order_release` semantic (because `memory_order_acq_rel` include it)

---

because still exist doubt, i try make yet bit another prove

given:

```
struct T { 
    std::atomic<int> a;

    T(int N) : a(N) {}

    void Release() {
        if (a.fetch_sub(1,std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1) delete this;
    }
};
```

- let a initialized to N (=1,2,...∞)
- let Release() called exactly N time

question: are code will be correct and **T** will be deleted ?

let `N = 1` -  so `a == 1` at begin and `Release()` called one time.

here exist question ? somebody say that this is "UB" ? (`a` accessed after `delete this` begin execute or how ?!)

`delete this` can not begin execute until `a.fetch_sub(1,std::memory_order_relaxed)` will be calculated,  because `delete this` **depended from result** of `a.fetch_sub`. compiler or cpu can not reorder `delete this` before `a.fetch_sub(1,std::memory_order_relaxed)` finished.

because `a == 1` - `a.fetch_sub(1,std::memory_order_relaxed)` return 1, `1 == 1` so `delete this` will be called.

and all access to object before `delete this` begin execute.

so code correct and `T` deleted in case `N == 1`.

let now in case `N == n` all correct. so look for case `N = n + 1. (n = 1,2..∞)`

- `a.fetch_sub` is modifications of atomic variable.
- All modifications to any particular atomic variable occur in a total
  order that is specific to this one atomic variable.
- so we can say that some `a.fetch_sub` will be executed **first** (in
  order of modification **a**)
- this **first** (in order of modification **a**) `a.fetch_sub` return
  `n + 1 != 1 (n = 1..∞)` - so `Release()` in which will be executed this
  **first** `a.fetch_sub`, exit without call `delete this`
- and `delete this` **yet not called** - it will be called only
  **after** `a.fetch_sub` which return 1, but this `a.fetch_sub` will be called **after first** `a.fetch_sub`
- and will be `a == n` after **first** `a.fetch_sub` finished (this
  will be **before** all other `n` `a.fetch_sub`)
- so one `Release` (where **first** `a.fetch_sub` executed ) exit
  without `delete this` and it finish access object **before** `delete this` start
- we now have `n` rest `Release()` calls and `a == n` before any
  `a.fetch_sub`, but this case already OK

---

one more note for those who think that code not safe / UB.

not safe can be only if we begin delete before any access of object finished.

but delete will be only after `a.fetch_sub` return 1.

this mean that another `a.fetch_sub` already modify `a`

because `a.fetch_sub` is atomic - if we view it side effect (modification of `a`) - `a.fetch_sub` - no more access `a`

really if operation write value to memory location (`a`) and after this access this memory again - this already not atomic by sense.

so if we view result of atomic modification - it already completed and no more access variable

as result delete will be already after all access to `a` complete.

and here not need any special memory order (relaxed,acq,rel) for atomic. even relaxed order is ok. we need only atomicity of operation.

`memory_order_acq_rel` need if object T containing not only `a` counter. and we want in destructor view all memory modifications to another fields of T

Comment: Ok, got it. I didn't pay enough attention to the value of `T::a` The thread that happens to run first will never be able to delete `t`.

Comment: @J.Doe - yes, this i and mean at very begin. *The thread that happens to* execute atomic `a.fetch_sub` first. not run (this is undefined)

Comment: Right. This works nicely **if we assume that the threads will only run once**.

Comment: @super - this is by task condition. of course if we several time call `Release` (more than reference count) will be error even with single thread. so unclear what you try to say

Comment: @super - in general need implement `AddRef` and `Release` on object. before pass object to thread - call `AddRef`. when thread no more use object - it call `Release`. and This works nicely if we assume that will be correct calls to `AddRef` and `Release`.

Comment: I'm simply pointing out that this works under certain assumptions, since it's not specified in the question but assumed by both OP and you. Hopefully it will clarify for future readers.

Comment: _so all Release occur in a total order_.. True, but the destruction of the atomic is unordered wrt the RMW operations

Comment: @LWimsey - and what you try to say ? delete will be called **only once** and **after** all `Release` - so what you mean under `destruction of the atomic is unordered` ? `delete` is sequenced **after** `Release` call in the **same** thread (X). and this **last** `Release`  in this thread (X) is sequenced **after** all another `Release` in another threads.

Comment: Memory access to destruct `a` is non-atomic. You cannot assume inter-thread ordering wrt the RMW operations.

Comment: @LWimsey - delete called **after** `fetch_sub` in the **same** thread

Comment: @LWimsey - look for [Relaxed ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Relaxed_ordering) example - *although A is sequenced-before B within thread 1* - this part.. i try to say that `fetch_sub` is **sequenced-before** `delete` in any thread

Comment: I get what you are saying, but in the cppreference example, all atomic operations occur in some order. The code posted by the OP destructs memory without ordering. Program order alone is not enough

Comment: @LWimsey - *destructs memory without ordering* ordering **between what ?** in my understand any order must be between something. so i not understand what you try say. in case object T was more complex, here not only `a` - i note that need `memory_order_acq_rel` in `Release` for view all side effects in destructors. are you can write example/POC look like here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order with assert - for be concrete - where can be error

Comment: @RbMm: you might want to quote the ISO C++ standard itself. https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#14 "*The value of an atomic object M, as determined by evaluation B, shall be the value stored by some side effect A that modifies M, where B does not happen before A.*" this formally ties "happening" order to the modification order that the standard says must exist.

Comment: So it *formally* rules out the possibility of the first `fetch_sub`'s access to the memory happening after that memory is deleted.  (Because that could only happen if it "happened" in the opposite order from modification, but the standard rules that out.  That *would* be B (the fetch_sub in the deleting thread) happening before the A (fetch_sub in the other thread)).  This was already obvious for any real CPU, but this is the language in the standard that guarantees it in standardese.

Comment: @PeterCordes let me clarify your the thought is whether i understood you correctly.
*modificatiom order* of **a** formal != *"happening" order*. --
The value **1** of an atomic object **a**, as determined by evaluation **B** (`a.fetch_sub`), shall be the value stored by some side effect **A** (`a.fetch_sub`) that modifies **a**, where *B* *does not happen before* **A**. -- *does not happen before* + *total order* -> *happen after*  ?

Comment: @PeterCordes are we can say that `delete this` *does not happen before* `a.fetch_sub(.)` which view and return **1**,  and it  *does not happen before* **another** `a.fetch_sub(.)` (which view and return not **1**). so `delete this` *does not happen before*  **any** `a.fetch_sub` return ?

Comment: but formal we can say *does not happen before* != *happen after* ? i have problem and with english at this not simply standard . but i try use generic logic, anyway standard rules try be designed for this, for be possible formal prove such things

Comment: The important point is that we only have a problem if A (the fetch_sub in the non-deleting thread) can run after or at the same time as `delete`.  For *that* to happen, it would have to be strictly after B.  Simultaneous with B would still be safe, because B happens before `delete`.  The "not after" wording *does* allow for them to happen at the same time.  (On real implementations on CPUs with MESI, simultaneous is impossible.  At least when we're talking about 2 separate RMW operations.)  But that's not the point.  Although yes, the modification order does imply that RMWs have an order.

Comment: @PeterCordes - will be correct say so - https://pastebin.com/nkMptN71 ? i bit not sure in 2.) correct (or the best) formulated

Comment: Yes, I think your logic is correct.  Your point 2. allows **B** before **A**.  But 1. already rules that out by the definitions of A and B and the initial value of the object being `2`.  But I think the way you wrote it, you're not trying to only build on previous results, just stating separate known facts.

Comment: Note that if one thread was doing relaxed `a = 1` instead of relaxed `a--`, it could be simultaneous but we'd still never have use-after free.  Sometimes we might not have a deletion at all, but in cases where the `t->a--` sees the value from `t->a=1` it means it wasn't after, and thus couldn't come after delete.

Comment: But you need take into account, that other thread could addRef between if (a.fetch_sub(1,std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1) and delete this. So, the other thread should check addRef result. If it's 0, then it already deleting.

Comment: @sibvic - *that other thread could addRef between* - for call *AddRef* - need **already** have reference to object. if *a.fetch_sub(1,std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1* - this mean - this is **last** reference and nobody else have reference, so nobody (threads) can call *AddRef* anymore.

Comment: @sibvic - i try even say like that - for any access for object (including `AddRef` of course ) need for begin have reference to object. you can ask - what sense call `AddRef`  if we already have reference ? for example for pass object pointer to another thread, return object pointer to external caller, or exist and more case, say shell some call to object in `p->AddReff(); p->somefunc(); p->Release()` (in case inside p->somefunc() can be called Release). and here i not use describe weak reference or rundown protection, it not need by concrete task

Comment: @RbMm Quite often it used like so: `Obj* getObj() { if (mObj != nullptr) { mObj->AddRef(); return mObj;} return nullptr; }` In that case it is possible `if (mObj != nullptr)` could already have 0 refs (the other thread already `->Release()` it but haven't assign `nullptr` yet

Comment: @sibvic - how this related to my answer ? i already explain - we can not call any method on object (including of course `AddRef`) if we not have reference on object.

Comment: @RbMm The same object owner could addref/release it in different threads. I had a crash on my project: two thread deleting the same object despite using std::atomic + fetch_* functions. My note may help someone with the same case.

Comment: @sibvic - *The same object owner could addref/release it in different threads* - and so what ? *I had a crash on my project:* - but how your crash related to my answer ?

Comment: @sibvic - *My note may help someone with the same case* - what your note ? absolute unclear and as result not helpfully.

Answer (score 4):

This should be safe ***assuming each thread only runs once*** because `t` wouldn't be deleted until both threads have already read the pointer. Although I would still strongly recommend the use of a `std::shared_ptr` if you want to manage the lifetime of a pointer with reference counting instead of trying to do it yourself. That's what it was made for.

> *suppose Thread 1 will execute the* `delete`*. Is it guaranteed that when Thread 1 started the* `delete`*, Thread 2 won't even read* `t`*?*

Yes, in order for thread 1 to delete `t`, the read in the second thread that decrements the value must have already occurred otherwise the `if` statement would not have evaluated to true and `t` would not have been deleted.

Comment: how interesting reference counting worked in this case ? are you know this topic ?

Comment: @RbMm, There is no reference counting going on here because this is a raw pointer. If you want reference counting you should be using `std::shared_ptr`. Although I can't personally speak for the thread safety of `std::shared_ptr` because I haven't looked into it.

Comment: @RbMm You are clearly missing the simple problem here that everyone else is clearly seeing. Reference counting does not help if you try to dereference a `delete`d pointer.

Comment: @RbMm The counter `a` is a **member of `t`**. To check the counter you need to dereference `t`. But it might already be deleted.

Comment: @super, in this specific example `t` will not be deleted until after it is already done being used unless one of the threads executes more than once. If one or both of the threads is executed more than once then you are correct, you can run into a situation where `t` will be dereferenced after it has been deleted.